# Python Tkinter manually column editing

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to add a column in python tkinter in which I will manually add negative, positive and neutral comments.

Code:-

```
root=Tk()
def openInstruktion():
    from subprocess import call
    call("notepad c:\\Users\\Desktop\\tweets.txt")

instruktionBtn = Button(root, text='tweets', command=openInstruktion)
instruktionBtn.grid(row=6, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Currently, I am using this code & from it I am able to get sentences in my gui.

Comment: You didn't ask a question. What do you need help with?

Comment: I want to add a column in python tkinter in which I will manually add negative, positive and neutral comments.How can I do it?

Comment: Basically, I am loading the data from a text file & then I want to create a (n*2) table where n is my no. of sentences in the text file and 2nd is sentiment column which will accept string values like neutral,positive and negative (manually by me in gui).

Comment: You use `Notepad` a external Program I see no way to read Data from there. You have to read the Text File by your Python code.

Comment: You might get some better answers if you showed an example of what is inside the .txt file. At the moment, this is a very poorly asked question.

Comment: @scotty3785 the following is written in my text file:-
"arundhati bhattacharya(present sbi chief) was one of the committee members who signed the report to compensate adan\u2026 "
"pathetic excuse by cbi fon ndtv raid. sharehoder of icici complained! not the bank. i have an sbi share. will they raid adani i\u2026"
"pathetic excuse by cbi fon ndtv raid. sharehoder of icici complained! not the bank. i have an sbi share. will they raid adani i\u2026"

Comment: @Shirohige you should place that text in your question formatted so people can see it.